# Why did this question receive 4 close votes?

Tags: discussion

I asked this [question](https://superuser.com/q/757979/116475):

> Title: Cancel adding several tracks into a playlist in Traktor
>
> Body: I mistakenly added 10 tracks at once into a playlist in Traktor:
>   is there any way to cancel the operation right after I added them,
>   without having to go into the playlist and deleting manually?

I see that they are 4 close votes, all complaining that

> This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the
>   scope defined in the help center.

I don't understand. Traktor is a software and I'm asking a question about its use. What's the issue?

Comment: Maybe because the first result from Google: Android/iPhone app. http://www.native-instruments.com/en/traktor/

Comment: @Sathya Thanks, OS added. (Windows)

Comment: I have the slightest bias here, but adding a screenshot of what you're seeing might help, both to make it VERY clear it is in windows, and in case the solution is something obvious

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks, screenshot added!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help you in future posts here are a few tips to help you out:

1. If you ask a question regarding a specific set of software, place a link to the said software into your question.  That way people can know exactly what software you're talking about.
2. Pictures speak a thousand words.  Screen shots are great and help bring clarity (just don't use too many either, remember they speak a thousand words and I don't want to have to process ten's of thousands of them).  Make sure the pictures you select are of the problem at hand.
3. Use tags.  Instead of just putting the OS in the body of the question, tag it.  In your case you would use [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7).

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the link. Regarding the screenshot, I often attach some in my posts but in this case I don't think it adds anything to the question. For the OS I'm pretty sure that the solution if any is OS-independent so I'm afraid that using the very specific OS tag might deter some people from answering. For yeah anyway good general tips, thanks!

Comment: While you may think that this is OS-Independent, it actually may not.  Keyboard-Shortcuts aren't the same across platforms.